# Check if type exists in ElasticSearch by NEST

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I use NEST in ElasticSearch I want check type exist follow code:

```
User user =new User()
{  
    Id=3,
    Key= Guid.NewGuid(),
    UserName="gholzam"
};

elasticClient.Index<User>(user);
```

Can I check user type exist in ElasticSearch? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for [types exists](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-types-exists.html#indices-types-exists) was just added to [NEST](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/504) and will be available in the 1.1 release.

Usage:

```
var result = client.TypeExists(f=>f.Index("myIndex").Type("myType"));
```

You can also grab the NuGet package from the CI builds [here](https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net).